# C# XML Element Count in XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

I need to get the count of `EmpList` Tag in Particular `<EmpTypeHeader>` and `<EID>.`

For example:

```
EID - 9991515720640 with 1st EmpTypeHeader(XML Node) tag Contains 2 EmpList Tag
EID - 4534545454534 with 2nd EmpTypeHeader(XML Node) tag Contains 1 EmpList Tag
EID - 8998653323    with 3rd EmpTypeHeader(XML Node) tag Contains 1 EmpList Tag
```

But when I select `EMPList` Tag count it shows a total Count of 4.

My XML:

```
<Employee>
    <EmployeeHeader>
        <Date>2016-01-07</Date>
        <Time>03:45:39</Time>
    </EmployeeHeader>
    <EmpTypeHeader>
        <EID>9991515720640</EID>
        <AAA>4</AAA>
        <BBB />
        <EmpList>
            <CCC>222</CCC>
            <DDD>3333</DDD>
            <EEE>2050-09-25</EEE>
            <FFF>000</FFF>
        </EmpList>     
        <EmpList>
            <CCC>555</CCC>
            <DDD>666</DDD>
            <EEE>2050-09-25</EEE>
            <FFF>000</FFF>
        </EmpList>   
    </EmpTypeHeader>
    <EmpTypeHeader>
        <EID>4534545454534</EID>
        <AAA>66</AAA>
        <BBB />
        <EmpList>
            <CCC>999</CCC>
            <DDD>008</DDD>
            <EEE>2050-09-25</EEE>
            <FFF>000</FFF>
        </EmpList>      
    </EmpTypeHeader>
    <EmpTypeHeader>
        <EID>8998653323</EID>
        <AAA>9999</AAA>
        <BBB />
        <EmpList>
            <CCC>11333334</CCC>
            <DDD>663312</DDD>
            <EEE>2050-09-25</EEE>
            <FFF>000</FFF>
        </EmpList>      
    </EmpTypeHeader>
</Employee>
```

And my code:

```
private void ReadXMLEmp()
{
    string eid = "9991515720640";
    string strFileName = @"D:\Raseeth\Test1.xml";
    xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

    xmlDocument.Load(strFileName);
    xmlNodeListEmpTypeHeader = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//EmpTypeHeader");                    
    if (xmlNodeListEmpTypeHeader != null)
    {
        int empListCount = 0;

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNodeEmpTypeHeader in xmlNodeListEmpTypeHeader)
        {
            if (xmlNodeEmpTypeHeader["EID"] != null && xmlNodeEmpTypeHeader["EID"].InnerText.Trim() == eid)
            {
                empListCount = xmlNodeEmpTypeHeader.SelectNodes("//Position").Count; 
                Console.WriteLine("EmpList Count : " + empListCount);
                bFlag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I was blind it appears. (deleted previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your XPath expression.  `//Position` will find all nodes in the document with that name, whereas you are only interested in descendants from the current node.

Change this to `.//Position` - the `.` refers to the current node context.

Having said this, LINQ to XML is a far cleaner solution that XPath and the old `XmlDocument` API, for example:

```
var count = XDocument.Load("path/to/file.xml")
    .Descendants("EmpTypeHeader")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Element("EID") == "9991515720640")
    .Descendants("Position")
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use .Net 3.5

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(strFileName);
int total = 0;
foreach(var eid in root.Descendants("EID").ToList())
{
   int count = eid.Parent.Elements("EmpList").Count();
   Console.WriteLine(eid.Value + " " + count.ToString());
   total += count;
}
Console.WriteLine("Total EmpList's: " + total.ToString());
```

I'm not really understanding the question. Did you want a total count of EmpList's or a count of EmpList's by EID? I did both.